# Split container, Panel2Collapsed = True, Tabbing not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

When I set the panel2Collapsed to be true the tabbing on the form stops working and it stays focused on the panel2 which is part of a split control.

Using ctrl+tab works to go back through the controls the opposite way works but normally the tabbing loops round to the first control after the last control on the form.

When looking at the actve control it focussed on:

```
-----System.Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel, BorderStyle: System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None NAME:
```

And the tab won't move past this, I've been looking at forcing the next control to be selected by using

`SelectNextControl` method with little luck!

Comment: You would have to post code that reproduces that.